# Stochastic integral with respect to stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Assume that the continuous stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is such that the integral
$$
Y_t = \int_0^t X_s \, dM_s
$$
with respect to some continuous local martingale $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is well defined and is again a continuous local martingale. Moreover, assume that the stochastic process $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is such that
$$
V_t = \int_0^t Z_s d Y_s
$$
is well-defined. How does one use the definition of the stochastic integral to show rigorously that
$$
V_t = \int_0^t Z_s X_s \, dM_s.
$$
What are the necessary assumptions for this? As a special case, one may assume that $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Comment: The result is pretty straightforward when considering the definitions locally. Indeed, one has $\mathrm{d}Y_t = X_t\mathrm{d}M_t$, hence $\mathrm{d}V_t = Z_t\mathrm{d}Y_t = Z_tX_t\mathrm{d}M_t$.

Comment: The differential notation makes it seem intuitive, but could you maybe elaborate on the answer? Namely, why does the last equality below hold?
$$
V_t = \int_0^t Z_s \, dY_s = \int_0^t Z_s \, d \left( \int_0^s X_u \, dM_u \right) = \int_0^t Z_s X_s d M_s?
$$

Comment: The proof that the stochastic integral (is the unique process that) commutes with the bracket can be found in any reference on stochastic integration. It is possible that Abezhiko is referring to defining the stochastic integral via this property.

Comment: First you need to show that the associativity property holds in the case of path-wise integration, i.e. when the stochastic integral can be interpreted as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Afterwards, you exploit the fact that the integral $X\bullet Y$ is the only process in the space of continuous $L^2-$martingales such that $[X \bullet M, N] = X \bullet [M,N]$ where $M$ is a continuous local martingale and $N$ is any continuous $L^2-$martingale.